# Power Query M Lookup on Same table with Filtering

Tags: excel, powerquery, lookup

I already have a Power Query on Excel that feeds off an Excel "loading zone" table. I plan to add a macro later to have the query refresh to add the new rows and delete loading zone rows afterwards.

I needed commenting to be available, which I was able to achieve by self-referencing this query and extracting the manually created comments column. The query has these and more rows.

[image: RawQuery]

What I'm now trying to achieve with Power Query is for it to lookup comments for the same Device ID but for the previous week.

Row 6 should therefore have "presenting issues" as a Last Week Comment value. The others should not have anything as there are no comments from the previous week.

Most solutions I see out there are for Power BI and DAX environments, which I would like to avoid.

Thanks community in advance.

Comment: Please post sample data as text data not images, so we don't have to retype things to help you

Comment: Thank you I will! I tried pasting the table directly and SO converted it to an image. Will try next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powerquery, merge the table on top of itself.

match Device ID on top to Device ID on bottom

match Last Week on top to Week on bottom

hit [OK] then expand the Comment field using the arrows atop the new column

[image]

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source, {"Device ID", "Last Week"}, Source, {"Device ID", "Week"}, "Changed Type", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Changed Type" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Changed Type", {"Comment"}, {"Last Weeks Comment"}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Changed Type",{{"Date", type date}, {"Week", type date}, {"Last Week", type date}}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"ID", Order.Ascending}})
in #"Sorted Rows"
```

| ID | Device ID | Date | Week | Last Week | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 777 | 26/01/2023 | 22/01/2023 | 15/01/2023 | presenting |
| 2 | 856 | 27/01/2023 | 22/01/2023 | 15/01/2023 |  |
| 3 | 968 | 29/01/2023 | 22/01/2023 | 15/01/2023 |  |
| 4 | 652 | 29/01/2023 | 22/01/2023 | 15/01/2023 |  |
| 5 | 621 | 30/01/2023 | 29/01/2023 | 22/01/2023 |  |
| 6 | 777 | 02/01/2023 | 29/01/2023 | 22/01/2023 | fixed |

[image]

Comment: I tried this method, which makes absolute sense, and the Comment value got deleted, then the Last Week Comment Column had the presenting issues value on every row.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what that means. Works fine with sample data above. just tested

Comment: It seems like it is overwritting all the Device ID column with the first value.

Comment: Your method did work perfectly. The problem was that since the actual table has more columns, I could not notice that I had to select ctrl down in order to make the joins with multiple columns. So I clicked on the week columns at the end without knowing that the device ID columns were being deselected.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are having a problem with the `Table.Join` method, here's another method using the `Table.Group` method, although I would expect the `Table.Join` method proposed by @horseyride to be more efficient:

*Please read the code and the code comments to better understand the algorithm*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Device ID", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Date", type date}, {"Week", type date}, {"Last Week", type date}, 
        {"Comment", type text}, {"Last Week Comments", type text}}),

//Group by Device ID
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Device ID"}, {
        {"lwc", (t)=> 
            let 

        //Extract Last Weeks comment
        //Then insert into the Last Week Comment Column corresponding to This Week
                #"This Week" = List.Max(t[Week]),
                #"Last Week" = Date.AddDays(#"This Week",-7),
                #"Last Week Comment" = try Table.SelectRows(t, each [Week] =  #"Last Week")[Comment]{0} otherwise null,
                #"Add to Column" = Table.FromRecords(Table.TransformRows(t,
                    (r) => Record.TransformFields(r,
                        {"Last Week Comments", each if r[Week]=#"This Week" then #"Last Week Comment" else _})))
                 
            in 
                #"Add to Column"
                
                }
            }),

//Reexpand the grouped table
    #"Expanded lwc" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "lwc", 
        {"ID", "Date", "Week", "Last Week", "Comment", "Last Week Comments"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Expanded lwc",
        {"ID",  "Device ID", "Date", "Week", "Last Week", "Comment", "Last Week Comments"}),

//Sort back to original order using the original ID column
//If that is not in the desired sort order, add an Index column at the beginning,
//   and use that to sort the data
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Reordered Columns",{{"ID", Order.Ascending}}),

    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted Rows",{
        {"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Device ID", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Date", type date}, {"Week", type date}, {"Last Week", type date}, 
        {"Comment", type text}, {"Last Week Comments", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]